# Installing Plugins in gvim on Windows 8

Tags: vim, plugins

I seem to have put the EasyMotion plugin in the correct location, but now there's an error loading it...  I downloaded "Lokaltog-vim-easymotion-1.3-0-g667a668.zip" from [here][1].

I had previously put EasyMotion.vim in $HOME/vimfiles/plugin, which was giving the following error message:

```
>Error detected while processing C:\Users\Willem\vimfiles\plugin\EasyMotion.vim:

>line   24:
>E117: Unknown function: EasyMotion#InitOptions

>line   39:
>E121: Undefined variable: g:EasyMotion_hl_group_target
>E116: Invalid arguments for function EasyMotion#InitHL

>line   40:
>E121: Undefined variable: g:EasyMotion_hl_group_shade
>E116: Invalid arguments for function EasyMotion#InitHL

>line   69:
>E117: Unknown function: EasyMotion#InitMappings
```

I now realize that there are two files and have gotten it working! As per the first answer, I have now moved autoload/EasyMotion.vim into $HOME/vimfiles/autoload, as well as moving plugin/EasyMotion.vim into $HOME/vimfiles/plugin

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have forgotten to install everything.

More precisely, the `autoload/EasyMotion.vim` file is supposed to go in `$HOME/vimfiles/autoload/` and the `doc/easymotion.txt` file is supposed to go in `$HOME/vimfiles/doc/`.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use [pathogen](https://github.com/tpope/vim-pathogen) to help you with your plugins.

Once you have installed pathogen and activated it in your `_vimrc`, installing a plugin can be as simple as unpacking it in `$HOME\vimfiles\bundle` and restarting vim.